# Improving performance reading from large Redshift table

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

In what ways can I improve reading the entirety of a large table (> 100 mil rows) on Redshift? I have a dotnet program accessing data from a large table and `SELECT *` is taking around 2 hours to finish reading

Comment: a) Do you actually need to read the entire table? Are you not filtering it afterwards? b) How are you executing the query? Adding the code you're currently using for this would be helpful

Comment: Yea I'd have to read the entire table, I was wondering if tweaking my cluster's WLM would change anything but I'd doubt it since it's only 1 long running query. It seems like my compute node is using a good amount of CPU initially but dies down pretty quickly which I'm assuming it's reading from disk at that point. Is there any way I can tune my Redshift configs to improve speed or am I stuck with having to figure out a dotnet workaround at this point (don't have the code but just using npgsql to run that `SELECT *` statement)

Comment: If you are wanting the _entire_ table, it might be better to `UNLOAD` the table to a file, then have your program process the file.

Comment: unfortunately s3 has issues with their objectstreams breaking and downloading to file takes slightly longer than this method

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things you can do (depending on what you are trying to do which you haven't explained):

1. Don't read all the columns (I expect you have thought of this).
2. Make sure the data is compressed (encoded).
3. Ensure you data isn't badly skewed (i.e. most of your data is on one slice)
4. Allocate more memory to the query reading all this data.  I expect that there is quite a bit of spill to disk, reducing this could have a big impact.
5. Increase the number / size of nodes in your cluster.  The disk bandwidth is directly proportional to the number of nodes.
6. Use Redshift Spectrum to do the initial paring down of data.  If you are doing group by / aggregation of the data then Spectrum can greatly increase the bandwidth for performing these initial actions of your query.  This is only a win if you are not moving all the data to the Redshift cluster.

With all the said I am doubtful that you are really having issues with disk reads for only 100M rows.  This is peanuts for Redshift.  Unless you have 1000 columns and a tiny cluster this won't take 2 hours.  Did you do a SELECT * with the result landing on your computer?  If so the 2 hours was moving the data to you over the network, not reading it from disk.

I hope the suggestions above help but if my guess is correct and there is something wrong with your measurements you will need to provide more information.  How large in GB is the table?  How big is the cluster?  What queries are you running?  Table info like skew and compression. Query actual execution timing. Something seems amiss.

Comment: Thanks Bill, looks like option 4 could help. The query is a straight up `SELECT * FROM table_name`. 3 of these queries are being run concurrently on 3 of the same tables (10gb, 117,000,000 rows, and 16 cols each) and the cluster is running 2 dc2.large nodes. The query plan shows that all 3 had the about the same Actual Time and Average time at 1 hr (both 96% of Total) and the Max time at 2 hrs (4% skew). *This was all run on an EC2 cluster in the same region as my Redshift cluster

Comment: So your 100M+ rows of data have to be moved from Redshift to the EC2 over a single ethernet connection.  This is the slowest link in the process by far.  On the Redshift console page you should be able to look at the "actual performance" of each step of the query and it will give the time it takes for each step to complete.  You will see that the scan of the table takes only a few minutes. Another way to measure would be to run "create temp table FRED as select * from <table>;" and while this would do a read, some redistribution of data, and a write, none of the data has to leave the cluster.

Comment: Right i ran a create temp statement on my local machine and total time was 88 seconds, much faster than a select star read. But I'd still have to read the entire table, is there a way I can improve that speed?

Comment: I'm with you now.  It's not Redshift table read speed that you are trying to improve, it is pulling the data down to an ec2.  Good news, I've done this too :).  I'll write another answer.

Answer (score 0):

I now understand that the speed in question is pulling the data down to an EC2 instance.  There are ways to speed this up as well.

The issue you are running into is that you are moving all the data through a single network connection.  The issue with this is that a single network connection has a lot of handshake overhead and since Redshift requires a fairly small network MTU (packet size) there is a lot of handshaking.  In addition the data is send uncompressed over the JDBC connection which takes more bandwidth than compressed data.  So even though you can bringing the data to a single computer (ec2) there is significant speed up that can be done.

So if the question is how can I speed up the data coming from Redshift over the JDBC connection, I'm sorry you can't do much (high network speed ec2?).  If instead you want to get the data to the ec2 the fastest there are improvements that can be made.

Believe it or not the fastest way is a 2 step approach.  First unload the data to S3 and make sure it is compressed and with "parallel on".  This will cause Redshift to start a data transfer from each slice to S3 - in your case 4 parallel connections.  (If you had a bigger cluster the parallelism would be even higher.)  Now you will have at least 4 files in S3.

Next you start parallel gets of these files from the ec2.  You want around 4 parallel gets so this could work simply in your case.  A bash script can be used to automate the process of having 4 parallel AWS CLI gets of the data running at all times (if you have more than 4 files).  When each file is download you want to uncompress them and this can be done on the fly - "aws s3 cp s3://bucket/key - | gunzip -c > file".  Last step is to cat these files together (if you need) and read them into whatever tool needs the data.

Because there is a lot of overhead in tcp connections and we have overlapping reads from S3, and the files are compressed this 2-step process can be significantly faster than the 1-step JDBC connection route for pulling large amounts of data from Redshift.  The limiting step is likely the single network card of the ec2 but this process can maximize the performance of this limited resource.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion and all the help Bill, I tried working with this solution using AWS' dotnet sdk rather than thru bash and it turns out it has slightly lower speed. unload + parallel s3 downloads for a 10gb table took a total of 5.5 min which is a huge gain compared to `SELECT *` (saving s3object responsestreams into filestreams). But it seems like the bottleneck is actually reading thru the millions of rows in dotnet. Looks like this might not be a redshift issue

Comment: It is not a Redshift issue as you say.  It is a network bottleneck issue.  It is critical that you have multiple processes pulling the files from S3 in order to get this to move as fast as possible.  S3 is a cluster of many many computers but your single ec2 is the limiter - you need to get the most out of it and multiple processes each getting a different file is key.  Be sure you have 3-5 separate processes working on the transfers.  In addition upgrading your ec2 instance to maximize network bandwidth - the downside of this it will cost more.